# Can't connect to SSH over VPN when using 3G only

Tags: linux, vpn, iptables, tcp

I'm having a bit of a strange problem that I'm not sure how to debug/fix. I have a Raspberry Pi connected to a Windows VPN via either a wired interface or 3G dongle. With the wired interface I can connect to SSH on port 2200 using the VPN-assigned address of the Raspberry Pi, however with the 3G dongle I can't connect.

I've just run tcpdump on the Pi with the 3G dongle in use, it does receive packets to port 2200 but doesn't send a response. `netstat --listening` shows SSH listening on *:2200. `iptables -L -n` shows no rules, and has `policy ACCEPT` for INPUT, FORWARD, and OUTPUT.

So something is preventing SSH from receiving those packets, but I've no idea how, and why it only effects it when connected via 3G.

What could be causing this problem?

**'ifconfig' output:**

> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:cc:ff:62
>
> ```
>      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
> ```
>
> eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 58:2c:80:13:92:63
>
> ```
>      inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>      RX packets:1394 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>      TX packets:1246 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>      RX bytes:324889 (317.2 KiB)  TX bytes:99862 (97.5 KiB)
> ```
>
> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
>
> ```
>      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
>      RX packets:13 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>      TX packets:13 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>      RX bytes:1020 (1020.0 B)  TX bytes:1020 (1020.0 B)
> ```
>
> ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
>
> ```
>      inet addr:192.168.1.127  P-t-P:192.168.1.120  Mask:255.255.255.255
>      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1396  Metric:1
>      RX packets:333 errors:8 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>      TX packets:366 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>      collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
>      RX bytes:19944 (19.4 KiB)  TX bytes:24857 (24.2 KiB)
> ```

**'route' output:**

> Kernel IP routing table
>
> Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
> default         *               0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
> **[VPNSRV]** 192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth1
> 192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
> 192.168.1.120   *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0

**PPP config:**

> pty "pptp **[VPNSRV]** --nolaunchpppd --debug"
> name **[VPNUSR]**
> password **[VPNPASS]**
> remotename PPTP
> require-mppe-128
> require-mschap-v2
> refuse-eap
> refuse-pap
> refuse-chap
> refuse-mschap
> noauth
> debug
> persist
> maxfail 0
> defaultroute
> replacedefaultroute
> usepeerdns
> nobsdcomp
> nodeflate

**Update:**

I've just tried an experiment of getting the Pi to connect to an external address vs. VPN address, it works when connecting externally, but any attempt to access another VPN IP results in 'no route to host'. So it's definitely a routing issue, but I'm not too good with routing & netmasks.

Comment: What 3G carrier are you going through?

Comment: Three, although this definitely seems to be a networking setup issue on the Pi, not the carrier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. The 3G dongle is operating on the 192.168.1.0 subnet, my VPN was operating on the same subnet. Changing the VPN subnet to 192.168.2.0 or any other subnet fixed the problem.

This is done via the IPv4 Networking settings for the VPNs "Incoming Connections" adapter by changing the IP address range to 192.168.2.1 - 192.168.2.200.